# Socket io: Update data on separate page automatically on form submit without refreshing

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

If I have two pages open, one page showing a table of my data, and the other page containing a form for users to input new data, how do I go about using socket io to automatically update the page with the table when the user submits new data without having to refresh that page? I'm able to get all the data in the table but am having the problem in which I have to refresh the page in order for the new data to show up in the table.

My logic with the following code is that I'm sending data from my form to the server, which sends it back to client to add to the table automatically since the socket is connected. I don't know why this won't update the table automatically but I'm guessing I'm confused on how socket connections work. Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

form.js

```
 var socket = io.connect();
 socket.emit('data', { data: formData});  // formData is data from form
```

table.js

```
var socket = io.connect();
socket.on('addData', function (data) {

    console.log("ADDING DATA TO TABLE"); // prints out first time but not when user submits new data

}
```

server.js

```
  io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    // once client connects send data to table.js
    socket.emit('data', { data: myData});

    // recieved data from form on client
    socket.on('formData', function(data){

       myData.append(data); // add new data to all data         

       // send all data back to table.js 
       io.sockets.emit('addData', { data: myData}); 

     });

});
```

Note: I made some print statements to check if the client is receiving the addData event and it is at first when it loads the data that is already stored in the server. However, when a user submits new data, those print statements don't occur. I have excluded code for adding data to the table because that is not the issue at hand, the issue is that client is not receiving the addData event when a user submits new data.

Comment: Can you confirm if the client is receiving the `addData` event? If it is, then it would seem the issue is with actually updating the table on the client. If not, then you should likewise check if the server is receiving the `connection` event.

Comment: Yes, I made some print statements and the client is indeed receiving the addData event. However, when a user submits new data, those print statements don't occur.

Comment: @user3226932 in form.js you are emiting `socket.emit('data', { data: formData});` change it to `socket.emit('formData', { data: formData});` you don't have a listener for *data* event on server but for *formData*

Comment: changed, still getting same error

Comment: Where's the code that sends a form to the server and receives the form on the server?  That's where you insert code to notify other pages of changed data.  If this is really all you have, I don't see how you can even get changed data from a form on your server.

Comment: the code is in the post, i have a form.js file that emits form data to the 'formData' event on the server, and I have checked that the server does indeed receive the form data

Comment: nvm problem solved. thanks

Answer (score 0):

So on your server you should have something like

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    // once client connects send him data
    socket.emit('addData', { data: myData});

    // recieved data from form on client
    socket.on('formData', function(data){

        // now update all clients
        // use io.sockets.emit to send to all clients
        io.sockets.emit('addData', { data: data.data});

    });

});
```

And on the client you need to emit

```
socket.emit('formData', { data: someData});
```

**Update**
Fully functional example:

server

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(8000);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('client connected');
    // once client connects send him data
    socket.emit('addData', { data: 'myData'});

    // recieved data from form on client
    socket.on('formData', function(data){

        // now update all clients
        // use io.sockets.emit to send to all clients
        io.sockets.emit('addData', { data: data.data});

    });
});
```

index.html

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>

    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
    socket.on('addData', function (data) {
        // will output *got data Object {data: "myData"}* once connected
        console.log('got data', data);

    });

    // this is to send data 3 seconds later so above console.log will output *got data Object {data: "hello"}* again
    setTimeout(function(){
        socket.emit('formData', {data: 'hello'});
    },3000);
</script>
```

Comment: tried this but didn't work, the same problem occurs: the client is not receiving an event when a user submits new data, that's why no data is being added to the table on the page unless i refresh

Comment: should i only have one connection open at all times?

Comment: Multiple clients can connect to server at the same time, if this is what you mean.

Comment: should the connection be the same for emitting the form data in the form javascript file and receiving the data in the table javascript file? Or should i be using different connections on the server?

Comment: @user3226932 Same connection. You only connect once from client to server and then you are emiting or recieving data on the same connection, can you add more of the code you have so we can see what you are actualy trying?